# "find -exec print" does not work

Tags: shell, ksh

```
> find . -type f -exec print {} \;
find: cannot execute print:: No such file or directory
> find . -type f -exec echo {} \;
f1.txt
f2.txt
...
```

Why "find -exec print" does not work?
Shell - ksh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `print` is a shell builtin, not an executable.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I should've said "shell builtin", not "bash builtin" ;-)